# Youtube API with Flutter issue

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-data-api

I have a private video on my YouTube channel, and I want to log in using the YouTube API in my Flutter app to display that private video. I've created an API key and OAuth client ID, and I've tried several approaches, but I still don't know how to display that private video. For public videos, it works fine. Can you please help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart' as auth;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SignInDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
   final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']);

  _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
       GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn!.signIn();
       GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;

      final auth.ClientId clientId = auth.ClientId(
        '1053900044752-7i1elhblnhdv0gjm92k91mnbl15u9fer.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        '',
      );

      final auth.AccessCredentials credentials = auth.AccessCredentials(
        auth.AccessToken(
          'Bearer',
          googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken!,
          DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)),
        ),
        googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        [],
      );

      // Sử dụng credentials để thực hiện các cuộc gọi API tiếp theo.
      print(credentials.accessToken.data);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Google Sign In Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _googleSignIn.currentUser == null
            ? ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Đăng nhập với Google'),
          onPressed: _handleSignIn,
        )
            : Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_googleSignIn.currentUser!.photoUrl!),
            ),
            Text(_googleSignIn.currentUser!.displayName!),
            Text(_googleSignIn.currentUser!.email),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, i can't sign in youtube.

According to my code above, am I using it correctly or do I have to use some library to use YoutubeAPIs?